# PHP echo size limit

Tags: php, file, xmlhttprequest

I'm using PHP to give pcap data to a Javascript function through xmlhttprequest. However I encountered some problem. Here is my PHP script

```
<?php
  $file = 'test.pcap';
  header('Content-Type: text / plain; charset = utf-8');
  header('Content-Length: ', filesize($file));
  header('Access-control-Allow-Origin: *');
  $handle = fopen($file, 'rb');
  $contents = unpack('H*', fread($handle, filesize($file)));
  fclose($handle);
  $content = array_values($contents);
  echo $content[0];
?>
```

Everything was working perfectly with small pcap file (ie around 1.5k) but when I get above 3k my script give nothing. I have made a quick test with the following loop:

```
<?php
for($x=0; $x<=2250; $x++)
{ 
        echo $x;
}
?>
```

And when I loop over more than 2500 I got the same issue with no more result. Is this issue linked to my browser or server configuration ?
Is there something wrong in my way of doing it ?

Any help will be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it without the header content Length?

Comment: It seems to be working thanks, but can you explain me a but more why the Content-Length header raised this issue ?